# Transactions in Berkeley DB. Fast?

Tags: performance, transactions, berkeley-db

When there is only one writer to a Berkeley DB, is it worth to use transactions?

Do transaction cause a significant slowdown? (in percents please)

Answer (score 0):

You use transactions if you require the atomicity that they provide.  Perhaps you need to abort the transaction, undoing everything in it?  Or perhaps you need the semantic that should the application fail, a partially completed transaction is aborted.  Your choice of transactions is based on atomicity, not performance.  If you need it, you need it.

If you don't need atomicity, you may not need durability.  Then, that is significantly faster!

Answer (score 0):

Transactions with DB_INIT_TXN in Berkeley DB are not significantly
slower than other models, although generally maintaining a transactional
log requires all data to be written to the log before being written
to the database.

For a single writer and multiple readers, try the DB_INIT_CDB
model because the code is much simpler. Locks in the INIT_CDB
model are per-table and so overall throughput might be worse
than a INIT_TXN model because of coarse grained per-table
lock contention.

Performance will depend on access patterns more than whether
one uses DB_INIT_TXN or DB_INIT_CDB models.